# Running 32-bit vs. 64-bit programs on a 64-bit OS

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

If I'm running a 64-bit OS (Windows XP x64 edition) and a program has both a 32-bit version and a 64-bit version, what are the advantages of using the 64-bit version? Will it be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP 64-bits is not more secure than 32-bits.

Vista and (better) Windows 7 introduced in 64-bit mode enhanced security with hardware-backed DEP, Kernel Patch Protection and mandatory driver signing.

So the only advantage in XP is that a 64-bits program can use more than 4 GB of memory.
However, practically speaking, no program needs so much memory, except in large servers.

Comment: No program uses more than 4Gb of memory? Except on servers? That's a bit strong, ain' it?

Comment: No, its totally correct. Also take Bubu's answer in account, you *may* notice improvements in performance. (Yeah I'm in that 1% and I did notice some 64bits are faster than the 32bit version.)

Comment: @Shiki - I'm not arguing performance (simply because I've no idea whether there is any). But a lot of programs use more than 4gb of memory. True, they may not be programs for a wide spectra of users, but nevertheless (think numerical computations).

Comment: Hm... Hardware DEP is available in 32-bit systems (including XP), and Kernel Patch Protection was ported back to Windows XP 64-bit in some update.

Comment: Idigas: Well.. but if one uses a PC for mathematical computation... ^^" | anyway: XP 64 bit is something what one should not use. Only Vista/Win7 comes with seamless support in my opinion. Even drivers on XP for 64bit can be a pain in the arse..

Comment: @Shiki Editing multiple ultra-high resolution images in PhotoShop or editing 1080p videos may also require massive amounts of RAM.  Though I agree that in general, most users wouldn't need that 4GB.

Comment: @Shiki - a huge percent of users use Pcs for computations (that is, percent of users who do such stuff at all). And you know since those fellows are always a little behind with their hardware and software; I would guess majority of them still uses XP. Vista never stuck and "7" is still missing support from a lot of software. @Emory Bell - one might also add CAD/CAM, different kinds of analysis programs ... the list goes on. More memory is always nice to have. Although, yes, most common users will not be needing it (but what is a "common user" nowadays ? who can tell?)

Comment: In any case, what I'm trying to say, is that I don't argue neither harrymc's nor bubu's answer; just the little "exclusively" part.

Comment: XP for x64  _is_ more secure than the x86 version. This is because it uses the same source code base as Server 2003 SP1, which had considerable security improvements over XP. These were impractical to back-fit into XP x86.

Answer (score 2):

if you run the 64-bit version, it will be able to address more memory, and if it is optimised well (as are some games) there may be a <10% improvement in performance. But in general it is not felt by the endusers.

i think most people run 64-bit just because of the memory addresing concerns.

Answer (score 1):

If the program does any of:

- access more than 2 or 3 GB of memory
- do arithmetic on 64-bit integers, especially multiply and divide
- assume higher CPU generation/feature-set in the 64-bit build and take advantage of *that* (e.g. SSE instructions)
- use the twice-as-wide SIMD registers to good effect

then 64-bit can be a *big* win.

If none of that is the case, then the 64-bit version will be larger and use more memory, and might be slower!  I've benchmarked a program and library tests built both ways, and the 32-bit version was faster. Apparently it caches worse, with the larger pointers leading to larger structures and the increased memory use prevents as much from fitting in the cache RAM at any given tier.  The additional registers did not make up for that.

YMMV with each processor generation and model and across brands.  But in general, *memory access* is a real speed bottleneck and that is a lasting trend.